# Notation for the d'Alembert operator

Tags: notation, mathematical-physics, laplacian, index-notation, quantum-field-theory

From the Wikipedia page [on the d'Alembert operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator) it is stated that equivalent ways of writing the d'Alembert operator are as follows,

> $$\begin{align}\Box =\eta^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu\partial_\mu = \partial^\mu \partial_\mu=\partial^2\end{align}$$

But is there even more notation for this operator?

I ask this as in QFT I have seen the Lagrangian density for the [Klein-Gordon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation) equation written as
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi - \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2$$
and equivalently as
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\partial_\mu\phi\right)^2 - \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2$$

So is it also true that
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \partial_\mu\phi - \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2?$$

If all the above is true, then there are at least $7$ different ways of denoting the d'Alembert operator,
$$\Box = \eta^{\mu\nu} \partial_\nu\partial_\mu = \partial^\mu \partial_\mu =\partial^2=\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi$$
$$=\left(\partial_\mu\phi\right)^2 =\partial_\mu \partial_\mu\phi\tag{1}$$

and similarly for the contravariant versions in the last equality above, $\left(\partial^\mu\phi\right)^2=\partial^\mu \partial^\mu\phi$.

In summary, do all these notations mean the *exact* same thing?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks for the reply, I appreciate that, but you can't possibly be serious when you say "You can write the thing literally in any way you want". Unless mathematicians/physicists are working in a framework where it is globally understood what a notation actually means, then this could lead to all sorts of confusion. For instance, I now decide that I will write $\Box=\lambda$, anyone got a problem?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez No, that's not quite what I meant, I'm glad you find it funny though :/ Can you please address the question? Are all those notations that I mentioned at the end of my post equivalent? A simple yes or no will suffice.

Comment: Generally, $\partial_\mu\partial_\mu \phi$ means you’re summing the second derivatives of $\phi$ (although to be strictly consistent with summation conventions and to ensure you’re contracting with the Minkowski metric you’d probably want one of those indices to be an upper index) whereas $\partial^\mu\phi \partial_\mu\phi$ means you’re summing over the squared first derivatives of $\phi$.

Comment: @kieransquared Yes, now we are getting somewhere, In my post I put eqn. $(1)$ next to those notations that I'm not sure are correct, the top line has the notation where there is one upper and one lower index, so the Einstein summation convention kicks in, which tells me immediately that $\Box$ is a scalar. But those last two notations, $\left(\partial_\mu\phi\right)^2 =\partial_\mu \partial_\mu\phi$ is what I am questioning, since with two covariant indices no Einstein summation can occur. So I really don't know if they are correct.

Comment: Your stated inequality is not correct. Imagine you’re only dealing with one coordinate (so you don’t even have a sum), then what you’ve written reduces to $(\phi’)^2 = \phi’’$ which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: When in doubt, write things out in coordinates.

Comment: @kieransquared That is exactly the problem, I'll try to locate the sources that use this notation, but.... apparently, it doesn't matter, it's just a notation and I cAn WrItE tHe ThInG liTeRallY iN aNy WaY i WaNt - not my words, just saying what someone else wrote in the first comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is it also true that
> $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \partial_\mu\phi - \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2?$$

No. We do not get the Klein-Gordon equation from $\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu \partial_\mu\phi - \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2$. As far as I know, the notation $\left(\partial_\mu\phi\right)^2$ simply means $\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi$.

Additionally, the object $\partial_\mu \partial_\mu\phi$ is not Lorentz-invariant. Note that
\begin{align}\partial_\mu \partial_\mu\phi&=\partial_0 \partial_0\phi+\partial_1 \partial_1\phi+\partial_2 \partial_2\phi+\partial_3\partial_3\phi\\
&=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2}+\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^2}. \ \ \ \ \ (1)\end{align}
On the other hand,
\begin{align}\partial_\mu \partial^\mu\phi&=\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu \partial_\nu\phi=\partial_0 \partial_0\phi-\partial_1 \partial_1\phi-\partial_2 \partial_2\phi-\partial_3\partial_3\phi\\
&=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2}-\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^2}. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)\end{align}
It is possible to show that Eq. $(2)$ is Lorentz-invariant, but Eq. $(1)$ is not.